# Best practice of Dependency Injection in Symfony2

Tags: php, dependency-injection, symfony

Before persisting an entity I need to copy and format some data in another table of my DB. I want this task to be performed as a service. 
So I describe the service in config.yml

```
services:
my_service:
    class: Acme\Bundle\AcmeBundle\DependencyInjections\MyService
    arguments: 
      entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

I was wondering the best way to call this service. The only way I can figure out is from the controller:

```
$entity = new Entity($this->get('my_service'));
```

Is that the best way to proceed ?

Answer (score 7):

If my understanding is good, your service my_service is something you want to do before persisting your entity. It's a service which has to be triggered by a prePersist event.

So, I'd just transform this service to a doctrine listener.

```
services:
    my_service:
        class: Acme\Bundle\AcmeBundle\DependencyInjections\MyService
        arguments: 
           entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

In MyService class, you have now to define a prePersist method with everything you want to do.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class MyService
{
     public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
     {
         $entity = $args->getEntity();
         $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
         (...)
    }
}
```

You can even remove the arguments of your service since LifecycleEventArgs provides a method to get the entity manager.

Finally, you have this listener

```
services:
    my_service:
        class: Acme\Bundle\AcmeBundle\DependencyInjections\MyService
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

I hope this answer your question

Comment: It perfectly answers the question ! Thanks a lot

Comment: you should mark this answer as correct if it answers the question!